# vue-next-select element not selecting value on selection

Tags: vue.js

```
import VueSelect from 'vue-next-select';
const app = createApp({})
app.component('vue-select', VueSelect)

 <vue-select v-model="tankno" :options="tanks1" searchable @input="form.tankno = $event.target.value" close-on-select label-by="tankno" class="text-left h-10 sinput" search-placeholder=" Search Tank No" placeholder="Select Tank No"  track-by="tankno"></vue-select>
```

When I submit form, `vue-select` not selecting value but only get on search input

Answer (score 0):

```
    <vue-select 
     v-model="tankno" 
     :options="tanks1" 
     searchable 
     @input="form.tankno = $event.target.value" 
     close-on-select label-by="tankno" 
     class="text-left h-10 sinput" 
     search-placeholder=" Search Tank No" 
     placeholder="Select Tank No"  
     track-by="tankno"
     @selected="onSelected"
     ref="selectRef"
    >
    
    </vue-select>

const onSelected = (e) => {
  selectRef.value.input.input.value = e;
}

In my case using Vue js 3, I create template refs (selectRef), then pass the selected value to the search input field.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).